# Can't load test.php while integrating simpleTest with CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp

I am a newbie for test cases.

I want to integrate SimpleTest with CakePHP 1.3.

I downloaded the latest version of SimpleTest, unzipped and added it to app/vendors.

When I hit http://example.com/test.php, I get a warning:

> Missing Controller for request /test.php

It might be a simple thing which I have missed, but don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved now by replacing test.php. I downloaded cakephp_1.3 and picked the test.php from there and placed in my app at app/webroot. Replacing test.php worked. Also used simpletest_1.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `mod_rewrite` is disabled.

If mod_rewrite is disabled the tests can then be accessed by browsing to **`http://example.com/app/webroot/test.php`**